# Set preview mode to pixels in illustrator after the fact?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pixel-grid

How can I set the preview mode in an illustrator document to pixel instead of default after the fact? If it is not possible, what would be a good workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err.... simply choose `View > Pixel Preview` from the menu.

Comment: Thank you! I *cannot* believe I missed that, I spent at least 10 minutes looking! This should be useful for other sudo-blind people that come along though.